# Java Stack pop() method in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, linked-list, stack

I have this assaigment that i want to try make all workers start their job and then each worker gets assaigned with a id and job. So far from the thread i have managed to start all workers however i cant assaign them with the jobs,i have tried `jobStack.pop();` which hoped that would assaign the worker with job however it outputs `Job@6577e002` which is not what i am looking for. so i want it to say worker 3 started job, worker 3 completed job 23. What would i need to do in order to get outcome like that.

Workforce.java

```
public class Workforce {

private final Worker[] pool;  // The worker population.
private int workerCount = 0;  // Used to generate each worker's ID and to keep a record of the number of workers in the workforce.

Thread[] workerThreads;

private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

// Constructor.
public Workforce(int size, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
    jobStack = theJobStack;
    resourceStack = theResourceStack;

    pool = new Worker[size];
    for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
        pool[i] = new Worker(workerCount, jobStack, resourceStack);
        workerCount++;
    }

    workerThreads = new Thread[pool.length];
    for(int i=0; i<workerThreads.length; i++) {
        workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);
    }
}


/// UNDER CONSTRUCTION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Starts all the worker threads.
public void start() {

    for(int i=0; i<pool.length; i++) {
       workerThreads[i] = new Thread(pool[i]);           
        workerThreads[i].start();
    }

    }

// Checks whether all workers have finished.
public boolean allWorkersFinished() {
    return false;
}

// Prints the job record of all workers.
public void printJobRecords() {
    ;
}
}
```

Job Stack.java

```
public class JobStack {

private final int MAX_TIME_REQUIREMENT_PER_JOB = 500;  // Milliseconds
private final int MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT_PER_JOB = 10;

private final LinkedList<Job> stack; 
private int jobCount = 0;  // To generate each job's ID.

private final Lock jobStackChangeLock;

public JobStack(int size) {
    stack = new LinkedList<>();
    Random rn = new Random(12345);  // Created with a seed so that random numbers generated are the same in each run.
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        stack.push(new Job(jobCount, (rn.nextInt(MAX_TIME_REQUIREMENT_PER_JOB)+1), (rn.nextInt(MAX_RESOURCE_COUNT_PER_JOB)+1)));
        jobCount++;
    }

    jobStackChangeLock = new ReentrantLock();
}

// Will return the next job on the stack or null to signal that there are no more jobs left on the stack.
public Job pop() {
    Job returnValue = null;
    jobStackChangeLock.lock();
    try {
        if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            returnValue = stack.pop();
        }
    } finally {
        jobStackChangeLock.unlock();
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public int getSize() {
    int returnValue = 0;
    jobStackChangeLock.lock();
    try {
        returnValue = stack.size();
    } finally {
        jobStackChangeLock.unlock();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Worker.java

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

private final int id;  // Unique worker ID.

private final JobStack jobStack;  // Reference to the job stack.
private final ResourceStack resourceStack;  // Reference to the resource stack.

private Job job;  // Job being processed.
private Resource[] resources;  // Resources being used for job being processed.

private boolean busy;  // Indicates the status of the worker. True when they are working (executing jobs) and false when there are no more jobs left to execute.

private final Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> jobsCompleted;  // The job record of the worker. Stores each job's ID and the IDs of the resources used for each job.

// Constructor.
public Worker(int theId, JobStack theJobStack, ResourceStack theResourceStack) {
    id = theId;
    jobStack = theJobStack;
    resourceStack = theResourceStack;
    job = null;
    busy = true;
    jobsCompleted = new TreeMap<>();
}


/// UNDER CONSTRUCTION /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


public void run() {

    try
    {
        System.out.println ("Worker " + id +" started job  ");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Throwing an exception
        System.out.println ("Exception is caught");
    }

   }
  }
```

Comment: Your code is not complete enough to be tested yet.  You don't actually start any threads (you never invoke your `start()` method.  Even if you did nothing would happen because your workers never attempt to get jobs from the job stack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't mention what's the Job class. So I can assume only that the Job class has some methods, and one of them is Job.getId(). Next assumption is that getId() returns the jobCunt parameter of the Job() constructor. Then this just should work:

```
public void run() {
    for (Job job = jobStack.pop(); job != null; job = jobStack.pop()) {
        try
        {
            System.out.println ("Worker " + id +" started job  ");
            job.doJob();   
            System.out.println("Worker " + id + " started job " + job.getId());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {            
            System.out.println ("Exception is caught");
        }
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Its all good but i am stuck in resources part now, how can i do same as job and do resource.pop();